# Is there a way to find prices from departure city to multiple cities or countries at once?

Tags: europe, tickets, airlines

I'm looking for airline ticket prices, and since my route around Europe is essentially one big circle, it doesn't really matter where I start. I just want to find the cheapest tickets that will get me to Europe. Is there a way to look for airline prices for City ABC to Europe? Or City ABC to a list of any of these 30 destinations? (The choice of 30 was arbitrary, but I was thinking of pooling a list of all capitals or major cities in my route and including all the airports within, say, a 25 mile radius of *each* of those cities).

As of now, I'm just doing city by city and it's making it difficult to compare prices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on many booking sites like kayak.com, you can enter in multiple airports into the airport box.

So instead of just LHR (London Heathrow), you can put LHR, CDG (Paris), CPH (Copenhagen), AMS (Amsterdam).

You could also on kayak choose nearby airports and it lets you select up to 4, but I prefer to just type them in.

For a really big list, you'd do it on the all-powerful [Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) site, which allows you to click 'nearby' on an airport and search all airports within x miles.  However, this will only show you what's available - you can't book on this site, and will then have to figure out how to find it on other websites.

Another possible mechanism is [Skyscanner's](http://www.skyscanner.net/) search.  Enter in your home city, and no destination. Set the dates and go.  It'll show you a list of prices in order to all possible countries. Click a country, and it'll show you ranked cities by price.

However, it's not perfect, and often misses charges by some airlines (eg RyanAir).

Answer (score 0):

[Kayak Explore](http://www.kayak.com/explore/) does exactly what you're after.  The results are based on historical data (ie, from the past few days) so occasionally you get results that aren't currently available, but it's a very good starting point.